# How do I change the select capability on all columns using DT table in Shiny App?

Tags: shiny, datatable, selector, dt

I want to have the select capability only on the second column using DT Package in shiny apps.

In this post this question [was asked](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32074/how-do-i-ignore-select-for-specified-column)

Using the above solution in DT package in shiny is not working for me. I expect by the code below that clicking on the second column, only, row will be selected.
Any hints on how I use the selector correctly?

```
data <- data.frame(
  a = 1:10,
  b = letters[1:10]
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(
      data = data,
      options = list(
        select = list(
          style = "os",
          selector = 'tr>td:nth-child(2)'
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = F)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector is alright, the functionalities to enable a "better" selection are contained in the `Select` extension. As documented [in the extensions page](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html), you need:

- Enable the `Select` extension
- Turn off DT’s own select functionality:

```
data <- data.frame(
  a = 1:10,
  b = letters[1:10]
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(
      data = data,
      options = list(
        select = list(
          style = "os",
          selector = 'tr>td:nth-child(2)'
        )
      ),
      extensions = c("Select"),
      selection = 'none'
    )
  }, server = F)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```